# Swap integers using pointers

Tags: c++, c, pointers, swap

Consider the function :

```
void swap (int *p,int *q)
{
    int temp;
    temp=*p;
    *p=*q;
    *q=temp;
}
```

`swap(4 , 5)`

**Output:**

```
5    4
```

I am aware that this is the right way to swap two integers using pointers, as mentioned in the books. But what is actually going on in there? It's very confusing. Consider this function , where the step *p=*q is replaced by p=q i.e., with the indirection operator * removed .

```
void swap (int *p,int *q)
{
    int temp;
    temp=*p;
    p=q;
    *q=temp;
}
```

Now ,what would happen? In this case the output i get for

`swap(4 , 5)`

**Output:**

```
4    4
```

Comment: Probably you should read about pointers

Comment: Consider http://pw1.netcom.com/~tjensen/ptr/pointers.htm

Comment: Your code won't even compile, since you can't pass an integer literal where a pointer type is needed.

Comment: ..and even if you coud pass pointers to them, they would be read-only.

Comment: In your second example "p=q;" causes p and q to point to the same area in memory.

Comment: Be aware of `std::swap`

Comment: this has nothing to do with c++

Answer (score 4):

Think of an `int` as a box with a number in it, and think of a pointer as an entry on your clipboard telling you which box to look in.

When you do

```
*p = *q;
```

you're looking on your list to find out which box you should use for `p`, and which box you should use for `q`; then you're looking what number is in the `q` box, and copying it into the `p` box. You still have two separate boxes, and two separate entries on your clipboard; it's just that the two boxes have the same number in.

But when you do

```
p = q;
```

you're not touching the boxes at all. You're only changing your clipboard. You're looking up which box you should use for `q`, and then you're *scrubbing out the entry for `p` on your clipboard* and replacing it with the same entry that you found under `q`. Now you have two boxes, with different numbers in; but your clipboard contains two entries that are the same, and both direct you to the same box. One of your boxes is now unreachable (you don't have an entry on your clipboard pointing you to it), and whenever you look up `p` or `q`, you'll end up looking in the *same box*.

(It's worth noting that this clipboard is only used for executing this particular function, and it gets thrown away afterwards. Changes that you make to the pointers that you pass in as arguments to the function won't have any effect after the function has finished executing. But I'd get your head round the other concepts first off, before you start worrying about scope.)

Comment: @undur_gongor Yes, I'm describing what's happening in each line of code, within the local scope. OP is asking for help understanding what's going on line by line.

Answer (score 2):

Because you've *removed* the step where the `int` `5` is moved to `*p`, so you're only moving the `4` across to `*q` via `temp`.

Comment: @undur_gongor It matters a great deal for the purposes of this question: OP is trying to understand what each line of the code means, and how `p=q` differs from `*p=*q`.

Answer (score 1):

Note that `int *p` and `int *q` are pointers (represent memory addresses!!). So, when you write `p=q` you end-up with two pointers that point to the same address!!!

```
void swap (int *p,int *q)
{
     int temp;
     temp=*p;      // temp = 4
     p=q;          // p points at the same address with q (where 5 is stored)
     *q=temp;      // store 4 where q points
}
```

You now understand that both pointers point to a memory location where integer 4 has been stored! Both pointers point to the same memory location.

Comment: 1+ The only correct answer so far (besides *chiastic-security*'s, sry for overlooking it) ... - what a shame. It might be worth mentoning that the operation `p=q` does not influence the function's behaviour at all, it also could simply be dropped.

Comment: @alk You're forgiven :)

Answer (score 1):

In general, the best method for understanding what happens in code with pointers is to bring out a pencil and some paper and start drawing.
I used my computer for this, which is much, *much* slower.

Since `swap(4,5)` doesn't actually work, I'll assume that we have two variables in the code that calls `swap`:

```
int x = 4;
int y = 5;
swap(&x, &y);
```

The first two lines of `swap` are identical in both versions, so the first two pictures apply to both.

As you enter `swap`, it will look something like this:

[image: Step one]

As you can see, `p` points at `x`, and `q` points at `y`.
The value of `temp` is indeterminate.

[image: Step two]

Now we have followed the `p` pointer (`*p`) and copied the value of `x` into `temp`.

**Version one:**

[image: Step three]

Here, we follow the pointer `q` (`*q`), fetching the value of `y` (i.e. 5) and then we follow the pointer `p` (`*p`) and store that value into `x`.

[image: Final step]

And lastly, we follow `q` so we can store the value of `temp`, i.e. the value that `x` used to have, in `y`.

**Version two**

[image: Step three revisited]

Here, we copy the *value* of `q` into `p`.
Since `p` and `q` are pointers, they now point to the same thing (`y`).
As you can see, the variable `x` hasn't changed; we just changed `p` so it points somewhere else.

[image: Waffles and unicorns]

This step is exactly the same as in the first version: store the value of `temp` in `y` by following `q`.

Hope this makes it clearer.

Answer (score 0):

your program will crash  because you are passing constant value `swap(4,5);` and there is no address for `4` and `5`what `p` and `q` gonna point?

`void swap(int *p,int *q){
  ......
 }` 
expecting two variable to whom pointer `p` and `q` can point.

Comment: How can the program crash if it won't compile?

Comment: it will compile. because function invocation will be at runtime not compile time.

Comment: you will get warning like this: `[Warning] passing arg 1 of swap makes pointer from integer without a cast `

Comment: Sorry, I didn't notice the question was tagged with two different languages, and didn't know that C allowed such nonsense. In C++, it's a type error, diagnosed by the compiler.

Comment: @MikeSeymour yes if you save code as `.cpp` then it will give compile time error.

Answer (score 0):

Copy this code to your code editor and test run it. Try to understand what this code is doing using comments.

```
//Start from main() function
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

// We are here from main function
/*
    This function takes two arguments
    both are pointer of type int. When declaring
    a pointer of type int we write "int *x". Which means
    that the vaiable x is pointer and it can only hold
    an address of a varible instead of it's value.

    However, We now have addresses of p in x and
    q in y. We want to exchange values but taking 
    addresses of them instead. This is a bit confusing.

*/
void swap(int *x, int *y)
{

 int temp = 0;
 /*
    Things are more confusing in the line below.
    " * " is a multipurpose operator.
    1. When you put this operator in the middle 
        of two variable (like a*b ) then it works as a
        multipliyer.
    2. When you put it when declaring a variable 
        ( like int *x ) then it works as if you are
        declaring a pointer of type int.
    3. When you put it before a pointer variable name but not 
        declaring the pointer variable then it gives the
        value the pointer pointing to.

    In our case the third statement is happening. As x has 
    the address of p, *x means the value of p.
*/

temp = *x; // Here, *x = 10 (because p = 10) so temp = 10.

/*
    Here, we are replacing the value of *x (or p, which is 10)
    by *y (or q which is 20).

    So, after the execution of the line below
    we will have *x = 20 or p = 20. It means we are losing
    the previous value of p. This is the reason we kept the value
    of p in temp.
*/

*x = *y; // Now p = 20 and q = 20

/*
    The line below sets *y (or q ) to the value of temp 
    (which is 10).

*/

*y = temp; //Now p = 20 and q = 10

}

int main()
{

int p = 0;
int q = 0;

cout << "Enter p : ";
cin >> p; // Say you have entered 10. Now p = 10

cout << "Enter q : ";
cin >> q; // Say you have entered 20. Now q = 20

/*
    This line takes you to the swap function above.
    We are not sending p, q here. We are sending pointer
    or addresses of p and q.
*/

swap(&p, &q); // This line takes you to the swap function above.

cout << "p : " << p << endl;
cout << "q : " << q << endl;
return 0;

}
```

Answer (score -1):

The function which works correctly:

```
void swap (int *p,int *q)
{
    int temp;   //You take an integer variable
    temp=*p;    //You store the value pointed to by p to temp which is 4
    *p=*q;      //You copy the value pointed to by q to p which is 5, hence p points to 5
    *q=temp;    //You store the value in temp as the value pointed by q, hence q points to 4 as temp holds 4
}
```

Now the code with your changes:

```
void swap (int *p,int *q)
{
    int temp;
    temp=*p;    //You store the value pointed to by p to temp which is 4
    p=q;        //p and q are addresses, you equate them so the value pointed becomes equal, if you make change in one the other changes automatically. So basically the value of 'p' in the calling function doesn't change, the change is a local change as the arguments to the called function are passed by reference. So the calue pointed to by p is not altered in 'swap' function.
    *q=temp;    //Now to make the value pointed to by q as 4 

}
```

Comment: Why is this answer downvoted? It seems to answer the question in great detail. Is it incorrect?

Comment: @user2079303: It's due to the last "and hence p also will point to 4". It is misleading. The code calling `swap` gets two 4s because a 4 was copied from the initial `*p` to `*q`. Not because `p` was changed (this has no impact).

Comment: In the line p=q the addresses of both pointers become same. One can easily use the printf and run the code and checkout. As the addresses of both the pointers become same, they point to same location in memory, which when changed directly implies that the value pointed to by both will change.

Comment: Here's how it looks: *p = 4, *q = 5, p = 0x1b0efa18, q = 0x1b0efa1c.
temp = 4.
*p = 5, *q = 5, p = 0x1b0efa1c, q = 0x1b0efa1c.
*p = 4, *q = 4, p = 0x1b0efa1c, q = 0x1b0efa1c.

Comment: @undur_gongor The statement isn't strictly incorrect but yea, you are right; it doesn't answer the question. Neither does your comment actually. The point is "why the output isn't `5 4`" and the reason isn't copying of 4 to `*q` but the lack of copying `5` to `*p` (for the original value of `p`).

Comment: @vvvv it would make sense to inspect the result of the function outside the function and there `p = 0x1b0efa18` still, because the the pointers are passed by value rather than a reference. The value of the function local `p` is irrelevant. Except in the sense that once the original pointer is lost, the value can not be changed within the function, but I think it's enough to state that the function never writes to `*p` and thus it's value does not change.

Answer (score -4):

You can use the xor swap algorithm:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    int i = 1;
    int j = 2;

    int *p = &i;
    int *q = &j;

    printf("BEFORE: %d - %d\n", *p, *q);

    if (*p != *q)
    {
        /* swap */
        *p ^= *q;
        *q ^= *p;
        *p ^= *q;
    }

    printf("AFTER: %d - %d\n", *p, *q);

    return 0;
}
```

reference:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XOR_swap_algorithm

Comment: And how on earth this answers OP question ?

Comment: And BTW, it will fail if `p` and `q` are equal.

Comment: @P0W The explanation of the reason why already given (which I actually upvoted) is good.  I gave an alternate.  I'm not sure that was worth the downvote

Comment: I don't down-vote answers unless its spam and totally insane post. FYI. Down-vote is not mine